# HuggingFace Transformers model config reported "This is a deprecated strategy to control generation and will be removed soon"

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am training a sequence-to-sequence model using HuggingFace Transformers' `Seq2SeqTrainer`. When I execute the training process, it reports the following warning:

> /path/to/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py:1219: UserWarning: You have modified the pretrained model configuration to control generation. This is a deprecated strategy to control generation and will be removed soon, in a future version. Please use a generation configuration file (see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation)

Note the HuggingFace documentation link is dead.

I use the following codes:

```
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model.config.output_attentions = True
model.config.output_hidden_states = True

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "output_dir_here",
    evaluation_strategy = IntervalStrategy.STEPS, #"epoch",
    optim = "adamw_torch", # Use new PyTorch optimizer
    eval_steps = 1000, # New
    logging_steps = 1000,
    save_steps = 1000,
    learning_rate = 2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = batch_size,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    save_total_limit = 3,
    num_train_epochs = 30,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    remove_unused_columns=True,
    fp16 = True,
    push_to_hub = True,
    metric_for_best_model = 'bleu', # New or "f1"
    load_best_model_at_end = True # New
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model = model,
    args = training_args,
    train_dataset = train_ds,
    eval_dataset = eval_ds,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    data_collator = data_collator,
    compute_metrics = compute_metrics,
    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)]
)

trainer.train()
```

The training process can be completed without any problem, but I am concerned about the deprecation warning. How should I modify the codes to solve the problem?

Version:

- Transformers 4.28.1
- Python 3.9.7

Comment: Please show all the parameters you've used inside `Seq2SeqTrainingArguments` and `Seq2SeqTrainer`. Without that it's hard to pinpoint which arguments you used in those classes that's raising the deprecation warning.

Comment: Added. I thought it's related to the `model.config.xxx` lines.

Comment: @MaciejSkorski sorry for the typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thx, I believe I managed to understand the issue please try what I shared in my answer.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633368/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root-Cause**

This is a warning about *using the API in the outdated manner* (=unsupported soon). However, as of now, the code is fixing this on its own - hence only a warning not a breaking error.

See [these lines in the source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c23d131eabcfa2cc722b483b2577ac6a0afc13ca/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L1253-L1266).

**Remedy**

The `transformers` library **encourages the use of config files**. In this case, we need to pass a `GenerationConfig` object early, rather than to set attributes.

---

I will first share a clean, simple example:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration

model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn")

ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE = (
    "PG&E stated it scheduled the blackouts in response to forecasts for high winds "
    "amid dry conditions. The aim is to reduce the risk of wildfires. Nearly 800 thousand customers were "
    "scheduled to be affected by the shutoffs which were expected to last through at least midday tomorrow."
)
inputs = tokenizer([ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE], max_length=1024, return_tensors="pt")

# change config and generate summary

from transformers.generation import GenerationConfig

model.config.max_new_tokens = 10
model.config.min_length = 1
gen_cfg = GenerationConfig.from_model_config(model.config)
gen_cfg.max_new_tokens = 10
gen_cfg.min_length = 1

summary_ids = model.generate(inputs["input_ids"], generation_config=gen_cfg)
tokenizer.batch_decode(summary_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]
```

If you try to manipulate the `config` attributes directly and pass no config, you get a warning. If you pass a GenerationConfig, you are all good. This example is reproducible as a [Colab notebook here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/ba3ddbb611a775f4dd182d41c7bec99a/transformers_configexample.ipynb).

---

Now, to the original question. Note that, in general, [changing architecture configs of pretrained models is not recommended](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/102) for incompatibility reasons. This is [sometimes possible with extra effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603089/config-change-for-a-pre-trained-transformer-model). However, **certain config changes are possible upon initialization**:

```py
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
     "facebook/bart-large-cnn", 
     attention_dropout=0.123
)
```

Here is the fully-working code, corrected for reproducibility and [see also this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/bb08459f292e4b0cb16596667619ee44/finetune_bart_generation.ipynb)

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration
from transformers.generation import GenerationConfig
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers.models.bart.modeling_bart import shift_tokens_right
from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn", attention_dropout=0.123)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn")
seq2seq_data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model)

def get_features(batch):
    input_encodings = tokenizer(batch["text"], max_length=1024, truncation=True)
    
    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        target_encodings = tokenizer(batch["summary"], max_length=256, truncation=True)
        
    return {"input_ids": input_encodings["input_ids"], 
           "attention_mask": input_encodings["attention_mask"], 
           "labels": target_encodings["input_ids"]}

dataset_ftrs = dataset.map(get_features, batched=True)
columns = ['input_ids', 'labels', 'input_ids','attention_mask',] 
dataset_ftrs.set_format(type='torch', columns=columns)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./models/bart-summarizer',          
    num_train_epochs=1,           
    per_device_train_batch_size=1, 
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,   
    warmup_steps=500,               
    weight_decay=0.01,              
    logging_dir='./logs',          
)

model.config.output_attentions = True
model.config.output_hidden_states = True

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./models/bart-summarizer', 
    num_train_epochs=1, 
    warmup_steps=500,                                  
    per_device_train_batch_size=1, 
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1, 
    weight_decay=0.01, 
    logging_steps=10, 
    push_to_hub=False, 
    evaluation_strategy='steps', 
    eval_steps=500, 
    save_steps=1e6, 
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, 
    args=training_args, 
    tokenizer=tokenizer,                  
    data_collator=seq2seq_data_collator,                  
    train_dataset=dataset_ftrs["train"],                  
    eval_dataset=dataset_ftrs["test"],
)

assert model.config.attention_dropout==0.123

#trainer.train()
```

Comment: The warning still exists after the change has been made.

Comment: @Raptor, right I stated the right diagnosis but followed with a wrong recipe. You need to pass a config object, see the updated answer.

Comment: Please refer the my question, where can I fit in the `gen_cfg` in my code? In `trainer.train()`?

Comment: @Raport, I believe I root-caused and explained the core issue (as other upvotes demonstrated) as the code was incomplete. See the updated answer, where I added more on your specific case.